# Android, see network drives and shares

Tags: android, windows, networking

I'm a bit lost and I don't know where to begin, but I would like to learn about local networking and how to list directories in shared locations from e.g. my home PC. Lets say I have a couple of documents on my PC that I need to access from my phone. These documents are located in a shared directory (other PCs can access these through the network explorer in windows).

How would I list/access these files through my android device?

I'm not looking for "ready to go" solutions but my searches return references to already existing software - which I'm not interested in. I want to build my own.

Any good articles or tutorials regarding this topic? What is required and what problems will I face?

Edit: I should also add that I have previous experience of developing android apps so I'm not starting from scratch - I just don't have any knowledge of local networking.

Comment: Find an SMB client library for Java that works on Android, and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most apps that do this use [jCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/). I haven't used it, but it should have some examples to get you started.